How to yield control back to the event loop
import asyncio

async def long_running_task():
    try:
        while True:
            # Your long-running processing
            if asyncio.current_task().cancelled():
                raise asyncio.CancelledError
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Task was cancelled")

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(long_running_task())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Let the task run for 5 seconds
    task.cancel()  # Cancel the task
    print("cancelled")

asyncio.run(main())

task.cancel() never gets called because it is single threaded and long_running_task() never awaits anything.
(In my real problem, I have a blocking calls, which I don't want to run if the task is already cancelled. But the task never gets cancelled, because they are running).
How do I make this concurrent?

You have to plae the synchronous long running calls to run in other thread(s) - otherwise it does not even make sense to have async code to try to orchestrate things.
Check the docs of asyncio.to_thread  and asyncio.run_in_executor and pick one to use. (unlike "plain" multi-threading in Python, you can get the called functions return values with both methods)

Python has a global interpreter lock. You can only use multi threading for c code. You have to use concurrency.

It is not how this works. The  (GIL) will prevent two threads of running Python code in parallel, like in using 2 cores simultaneously - but it works perfectly fine for task switching and concurrent code so that both threads are updated concurrently in  a seamless way to the programmer. You can only add await asyncio.sleep() in your Python code, but if your have blocking calls, that is what you need to do. If you don't believe me, just either try it, or read some docs. But flatly denying what I am telling you, without trying does not seem the smartest approach.

Thanks, I forgot the operating system's thread scheduling, will interleave long running python only tasks? without the need to yield control event loop (which was wat the question was about).

Yes - for some simple code, it is easier to write multi-threading than async code.  "pure" asynchronous code require all I/O calls to be implemented assynchronously as well - and even them, some of the libs do use multi-threading and the calls I linked above under the hood (like Python aiofile does).
The big advantage of async is to be able to set the specific points the current task can pause and yield to the async loop (that is: whenever there is an await)

Whoops, this works in my MRE
await asyncio.sleep(0)


This will enable the async loop to step other tasks each time it is found - but the long duration synchronous calls will still block the asyncio  loop for their duration. Executing blocking synchronous functions in a separated thread should be the preferred approach.
